# Azure DF - when extracting a datetime from a database into a CSV it sometimes gets interpreted as a datetime2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

When running an Azure Data Factory copy from CSV to a Synapse table we get intermittent Truncate errors. The destination table schema (in Synapse) is a mirror of the schema we originally extracted the data from.

What we find happening is that the original extract misinterpreted a datetime as a datetime2 and render the relevant field as such: 2019-10-07 11:22:31.4400000
When we run the copy from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 to the mirrored Synapse Table this schema has the field as a datetime. 
The copy function attempts a conversion from string (being CSV and all) into datetime (as that is the same as the originating table) but fails. (Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.)
Interestingly this issue is intermittent - the original datetime field is sometimes correctly rendered into the CSV as: 2019-10-07 11:22:31.440 (go figure).

We have limited desire to refactor all our SQL Db Schemas into datetime2 data types (for obvious reasons).
Anyone know if we are missing something here?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use Data Flow with a Derived Column to correct the errant string format.

Comment: Not possible as our pipeline iterates through a bunch of tables and we don't have knowledge of the schema up front. Plus this will (likely) seriously slow down the process. We are doing bulk copies.

Comment: You say _ the original extract misinterpreted a datetime as a datetime2_ so it sounds like the issue is actually with your original extract process? You also say _this issue is intermittent - the original datetime field is sometimes correctly rendered into the CSV_ so again to resolve the issue you'd need to address whatever is rendering it to CSV

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Mapping of the source to Datetime:

- specify the date format "yyyy-MM-dd"
- Run the pipeline

Alternatively:

- Change the mapping of date format to string
- Use the stored procedure approach to insert/copy data